# Restrict app for Metal feature support in the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, core-image, metal

With iOS 11 developers are able to write custom Core Image filters directly in Metal. However, according to the WWDC session about the topic, this feature is only available on devices with A8 or newer. So I guess the device's `MTLFeatureSet` must be GPU Family 2 or 3 in the corresponding iOS 11 version.

When I now decide to build a filter pipeline for a new app based on Metal shaders, how am I able to restrict its installation to supported devices? As far as I can tell one can only specify that Metal needs to be supported, but that includes GPU Family 1 devices as well. Is the common "This app only support X devices" disclaimer in the app's description really the only option?

(The same applies for Metal Performance Shaders and any other features that are only available on newer devices.)